# How long is the cache refresh time in stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, display-names, network-profile, caching

I just changed my username, because I quit eating Unicorns. However, its been 2 days and in SE.com, it still shows my old username:
[image]
Also, I noticed that going to my profile page refreshed the cache:
[image]
So how long is the cache refresh time?